# How do I shape my output data for a time series classification problem using LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, multiclass-classification

I am wanting to use an LSTM for anomaly detection on a multivariate time series data. Let's say there are n rows each corresponding to a timestamp incrementing by an hour and d input features and d output flags for each feature. These flags are 0,1 or 2.
I know how to shape the input data (samples, timesteps, features.
So If I take m timesteps in a sample, when I give a 2D input as (1,m,d), I want the output to be the matrix m*d (which is the d output flags for each timestep across m timesteps in the sample.

1. How do I shape the output data and  layers of my NN for this ?

I have tried using keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array. However, for an input of (batch_size, timesteps, input features) it gives as output data (batch_size, output features) instead of (batchsize, timesteps, outpupt features)
I would be glad to give additional information as needed and would greatly appreciate any help.
Thanks and regards